# Many to many Field - Accessing attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these two models related by a ManyToManyField:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)

class Foo(models.Model):

    bar = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, blank=True, related_name='bb')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.bar.name
```

In the admin page I get this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I access to the name of *bar* in *Foo*? I see the dot notation is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : you can't.

Long answer : your question "How can I access to the name of bar in Foo" implies a given `Foo` instance always have one *and only one* related `Bar` (not zero, not two, not forty-two, just exactly one), but you're using a `ManyToManyField` which means a given `Foo` instance can have zero, one or just any (positive) number of related `Bar`. In this case, `Foo.bar` resolves to a queryset, not to a single `Bar` instance, IOW

```
f = Foo() 
f.bar.all()
```

is equivalent to

```
f = Foo() 
Bar.objects.filter(bb=f) # very weird related name FWIW
```

Actually in this case `Foo.bar` would be better named `Foo.bars` (plural).

If your intent was to have a one to many relationship where each `Foo` has one single `Bar` and a `Bar` has many `Foo`, you want a `ForeignKey` instead.

Comment: do you know if there's any way to solve it using an intermediary table/model?

Comment: A many-to-many relationship IS built on an intermediary table - that's really relational model 101 stuff. And it just won't "solve" anything, either your design is wrong (you choosed a many to many when you wanted a one to many relationship) or your question doesn't make sense (cf the semantic of a many to many relationship).